# Change cognito user pool user status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to change with my android App, Cognito user pool user status from FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD to CONFIRMED? or from RESET_REQUIRED to CONFIRMED?
If yes which API call can I use?
In fact, I imported users to Cognito and I don't find a way or any example on how to turn them to CONFIRMED status using my App.
Thanks

Comment: Using the adminSetUserPassword to set a temporary password on user in RESET_REQUIRED will change them to FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD.

Answer (score 15):

To change the cognito user pool user status from FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD to CONFIRMED-

**1.with aws-cli:**

- get a session token with the temporary password

  ```
  aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id us-west-2_xxxxxxx --client-id xxxxxxx --auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=xxx,PASSWORD=xxx
  ```
- set new password with the session token

  ```
  aws cognito-idp admin-respond-to-auth-challenge --user-pool-id xxxx --client-id xxxx --challenge-name NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED --challenge-responses NEW_PASSWORD=xxx,USERNAME=xxx --session session_key_from_previous_token
  ```

**2.with aws-sdk:**

- get a session token with the temporary password

  ```
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminInitiateAuth(
  { 
     AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH', 
     ClientId: 'xxx', 
     UserPoolId: 'xxx', 
     AuthParameters: 
       { USERNAME: 'xxx', PASSWORD: 'temporary_password' } 
  },  function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });
  ```
- set new password with the session token

  ```
  var params = {
    ChallengeName: 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED', 
    ClientId: 'xxxx',
    ChallengeResponses: {
    USERNAME: 'xxx',
    NEW_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
  },
  Session: 'session_key_from_previous_token'
  };

  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.respondToAuthChallenge(params,   function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });
  ```

**Note:** If get an error about "**Unable to verify secret hash for client**", create another app client without a secret and use that.

Comment: I used the aws-cli method given here to move my test user from FORCE_PASSWORD_CHANGE to CONFIRMED. Thanks for the answer. I think the original poster should consider marking this answer correct.

Answer (score 4):

To change the status of the user you just need to go through the respective flows. To change `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` to `CONFIRMED`, you would need to use the one time password and login and change your password. For `RESET_REQUIRED`, you would need to use the Forgot Password flow and that will change the status to `CONFIRMED`.